# Problem in listview.builder with multiple widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a list of items and based on a condition it should be displayed in Widget1() or Widget2(). It works fine up to there, the problem is when I get to the bottom of the list and want to scroll slowly up, the items rebuild and it jumps up and down the list.

Using the itemExent does solve the problem, but it's not the ideal solution. I need dynamic items.

Note: Widgets do not have a default size.

```
ListView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      cacheExtent: 10000,
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      //itemExtent: 450.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index < list.length)
          return MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                /// some mandatory providers
              ],
              child: some condition
                  ? Widget1()
                  : Widget2());

        return loading();
      },
      itemCount: list.length
    );
```

Comment: what do you mean "jumps up and down " .  the widget rebuild is flutter behaviour. what is the "some condition" ? is it caused up and down on your list?

Comment: Exactly, when rebuilding and moving up, it makes some sudden jumps. But it doesn't happen if the elements have a fixed size.

The condition is only if the widget is of one type or another. They display information in different ways.

Comment: Having providers inside the builder seems to be the problem. I would suggest keeping the MultiBlocProvider above the list view (and initiate the load) so that the BlocBuilders in the Widget1 and Widget2 already have the data they need by the time you scroll to it.

Comment: The solution of moving the MultiBlocProvider is a good one. But it also generates another problem: inside the widgets I show a username, but this is repeated in all the widgets. But it is a separate problem. Problem solved.